# mailDoc function not attaching PDF(Adobe Acrobat/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, adobe

Trying to execute a mailDoc function using a mouseUp action submit button.

I am at the point where it will open my email app with everything(including the email address I've set, subline, body etc) but not attach the pdf itself. Here is my code:

```
app.alert("Survey Submmited", 3);

var cToAddr = "(Insert email here)@outlook.com";  
var cSubLine = "Technical Skills Survey";  
var cBody = "Please find the attached Skill Survey";  
  
this.mailDoc({  
  bUI: true,  
  cTo: cToAddr,  
  cSubject: cSubLine,  
  cMsg: cBody  
});
```

Edit: Forgot to add this error message from the console(
GeneralError: Operation failed.
Doc.mailDoc:14:AcroForm:submitForm:Annot1:MouseUp:Action1)